# Trigger to use data from 2 rows

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

A bit of a background first:

I have 2 tables, HOLD and CALC. When I start a transaction, a row is created in the HOLD table with JOB_ID, STATUS:START, and TIME: SYSDATETIME. When the job is completed, another row is created in the HOLD table with the same JOB_ID, STATUS:END and TIME: SYSDATETIME. So when the transaction is completed, the HOLD table will look like this:

| JOB_ID | STATUS | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | START | TIME1 |
| 1234 | END | TIME2 |

I plan to create a trigger that activates after the status END data is inserted. This trigger will pull the JOB_ID and calculate (TIME2 - TIME1) and insert it into the CALC table as minutes or seconds only. So in the end, there will only be 1 row for each JOB_ID.

| JOB_ID | TIME_TAKEN |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 05:00 |

I'm currently having trouble with selecting the rows with the same JOB_ID as I keep getting error when I try to use a where clause, and how to insert the time into variables so I can use TIME_DIFF.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TEST".CALC_TRIGGER AFTER INSERT ON "HOLD" REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_STATUS VARCHAR2(1 Byte);
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.STATUS = 'END') THEN
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CALC(JOB_ID, TIME_TAKEN)
VALUES (:OLD.JOB_ID, NULL);
END;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ca you please provide data for `TIME` column in HOLD table? It will be with date or just time only?

Comment: there is another approach also you can consider. In the procedure where you are inserting END record in HOLD table, you can use another insert statement to populate desired record in CALC table.

Answer (score 1):

With sample data like here:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1234 "JOB_ID", 'START' "STATUS", To_Date('01.01.2023 17:12:35', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TIME" From Dual Union All
            Select 1234 "JOB_ID", 'END' "STATUS", To_Date('04.01.2023 10:10:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TIME" From Dual Union All
            
            Select 4567 "JOB_ID", 'START' "STATUS", To_Date('01.01.2023 17:12:35', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TIME" From Dual Union All
            Select 4567 "JOB_ID", 'END' "STATUS", To_Date('03.01.2023 11:12:13', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TIME" From Dual Union All 
            
            Select 6789 "JOB_ID", 'START' "STATUS", To_Date('01.01.2023 17:12:35', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TIME" From Dual Union All
            Select 6789 "JOB_ID", 'END' "STATUS", To_Date('06.01.2023 17:12:35', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "TIME" From Dual 
        ),
```

You can create a CTE to get your starting and ending dates(times) in the same row...

```sql
  jobs AS
    (   Select   t.JOB_ID "JOB_ID",
                (Select TIME From tbl Where JOB_ID = t.JOb_ID And STATUS = 'START') "STARTED",
                (Select TIME From tbl Where JOB_ID = t.JOb_ID And STATUS = 'END') "ENDED"
        From    tbl t
        Group By  JOB_ID
    )
```

... now you can get your date-time difference for any job id ...

```sql
Select  JOB_ID "JOB_ID",
        To_Char(STARTED, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) "STARTED",
        To_Char(ENDED,   'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ) "ENDED",
        Trunc( ENDED - STARTED ) "DAYS", 
        Trunc( (ENDED - STARTED ) * 24 ) - ( Trunc( ENDED - STARTED ) * 24 ) "HOURS",
        Trunc( mod( (ENDED - STARTED ) *24 * 60, 60 ) ) "MINUTES",
        Trunc( mod( (ENDED - STARTED ) *24 *60 * 60, 60 ) ) "SECONDS"
From    jobs
Where   JOB_ID = 1234
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--      JOB_ID STARTED             ENDED                     DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES    SECONDS
--  ---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
--        1234 01.01.2023 17:12:35 04.01.2023 10:10:10          2         16         57         34
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as an access to the table is not possible in `for each row` trigger, you need to use a compound trigger for this:

> ```
> create trigger trg_hold_
> for insert on hold_
> when (new.status = 'END')
>
> compound trigger
>   /*List of changed JOB_IDs*/
>   g_jobs sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
>
> after each row is
> begin
>   g_jobs.extend(1);
>   g_jobs(g_jobs.last) := :new.job_id;
> end after each row;
>
> after statement is
> begin
>   /*Insert the timing into CALC table for all added job_id*/
>   insert into calc(job_id, time_taken)
>   select
>     job_id,
>     /*MAX is used to select the latest start and finish*/
>     max(decode(status, 'END', time_)) - max(decode(status, 'START', time_))
>   from hold_
>   where job_id in (select * from table(g_jobs))
>   group by job_id;
> end after statement;
>
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> insert into hold_(job_id, status, time_)
> values(1, 'START', systimestamp)
>
> 1 rows affected
> ```
>
> ```
> select * from calc
> ```

> ```
> insert into hold_(job_id, status, time_)
> values(1, 'END', systimestamp)
>
> 1 rows affected
> ```
>
> ```
> select * from calc
> ```

| JOB_ID | TIME_TAKEN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | +00 00:00:00.558130 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TvumZaQZ)